# Typescript: How to suppress "No overload matches this call"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

So I have a React Native application that uses Native Base as UI lib and Typescript.

Now there is an [Accordion](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#anatomy-headref) which - as soon its expanded - renders a second (nested) Accordion. The problem is that TypeScript complains:

`A VirtualizedList contains a cell which itself contains more than one VirtualizedList of the same orientation as the parent list. You must pass a unique listKey prop to each sibling list.`

Which is perfectly fine. But when I add this `listKey` to my `Accordion`, TypeScript complains about `No overload matches this call.`

How can I suppress this warning? Because Native Base doesn't provide `listKey` as prop for their `Accordion`.

Here is the code:

```
imports ...

type Props = {};

const Test: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {

  const renderNestedAccordion = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <ComponentWithAccordion></ComponentWithAccordion>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const dataArray = [{content: renderNestedAccordion()}];

  return (
    <Accordion
      listKey={'acc'} // error
      dataArray={dataArray}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick fix:

You can try `//@ts-ignore` which should suppress the warning.

[For more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#example-3)

Less guilty solution:

If you look at NativeBase [type definition](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/index.d.ts#L881) for `Accordion`, you will see that there is no `listKey`. Under the hood, NativeBase `Accordion` uses a `FlatList`. We know from React Native [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L3900) of `FlatList` extends `VirtualizedListProps<ItemT>` that has a `listKey`.

Look at the `Accordion` implementation we see that `FlatList` [takes all props](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Accordion.js#L230) from `Accordion` which means all `FlatList` props should be supported. Therefore `Accordion` should extend `FlatList` props. You can add `listKey` to the `Accordion` type definition or send a Github issue.

Disclaimer: I have never used Native Base. The above conclusion is made by looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, is it okay/good style to do so? In my opinion there is no other way ... It just feels so wrong >.<